# Delete with where clause, Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to delete all records with a certain field.

```
db.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of Personnel)("Delete From Personnel Where clientId = @clientId", sqlP)
```

I have seen example where they used;

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM ...", someParameter);
```

But I don't have the `Database` member on my context. How can I achieve this with an sql string like above?

Comment: Is your context type `ObjectContext` or `DbContext` ?

Comment: DbContext should have the `Database` property.

Comment: I must be mistaken then.

Comment: Check to see if you have method `ExecuteStoreCommand()` then you've got an `ObjectContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two type of contexts with EF.  It looks like you are using type `ObjectContext` which does not have the `Database` property and thus does not have the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method.

With `ObjectContext` the related method would be `ExecuteStoreCommand()`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)